# Java saving strings

Tags: java, xml

I have a RuneScape Private Server project coded in Java, and am trying to code a personal "tag" that players can use. I have managed to do this, but everytime there is a restart on the server, their "tag" gets reset to "null".

Their "tag" is initalized by doing a command ";;settag [name]". Their tag is then set to whatever they want. I have done this through a string:

```
      if (command[0].equals("settag")) {
            newTag = getCompleteString(command, 1);
newTag = player.yellTag
                player.sendMessage("Your tag is now:" +newTag);
            }
```

I am unsure what the most efficient way to fix this would be, I am thinking of just loading and saving through .xml/.txt files. By the way, player.yellTag is where the next command (::mytag) searches it from, which works fine, until there is a restart of the server.

Answer (score 0):

it all depends on the context of your application. If you are planning on having less than a few hundreds players, then a `xml` file may be ok. You should look at [JAXB](https://jaxb.java.net), which is, afaict, the standard way to store your objects in Java. You can also store them as JSON files, using [gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) which is way simpler to use and implement than XML stuff.

But if you get to have more than thousands of players, you may want to get some more efficient way to serialize your tags by putting them in a database, and thus an ORM library like [hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org) could help you do that.

You may want to make your own stuff, like a `tag` directory full of files named after unique ids of your players containing the players' tag... It's a lot more "hackish" but still quite efficient.

Comment: Thank you, the source I am already working with has efficient XML loading, so the logical thing would be to follow that. These tags would only be allowed a maximum of 12 characters, so it wouldn't be too massive. Thank you a huge amount though.

Comment: I was unsure on how to do this; because there is another source that had this feature; and it wasn't advanced whatsoever (in terms of code); and I was personally struggling on something as simple as keeping a string the same

Comment: I don't really get what you've got as XML loading/storing stuff, and what you don't have. I first understood you were looking for a way to store your data and had nothing yet.... May you make your question more precise?